# Why does my custom editor in Unity constantly run events like button clicks for example? It also does this on mouse over anywhere in window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

Ok, so it's been a while and I am attempting to make a custom editor. Also tried custom editor window. I have three buttons modifying properties on another script etc. Simple right? Problem is, In the custom editor, all events are triggering without me doing anything. I placed debug statements to test "1","2" "3" etc. and it print them out in order over and over again forever like it is in an update routine. These are three click events. Driving me nuts and googling useless. My Code

`

```
using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEditor;
   [CustomEditor(typeof(Modify))]
   [CanEditMultipleObjects]

    public class CloudsEditor : Editor
    {
        SerializedProperty powerSetting;
    string powerSettingText;
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        powerSetting = serializedObject.FindProperty("CloudsOnePowerSetting");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        Modify myScript = (Modify)target;
        serializedObject.Update();
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Set Clouds Fade");
        if (GUILayout.Button("Fast")) GUILayout.Width(100);
        {
            powerSetting.floatValue = 0.001f;
            powerSettingText = "0.001f";
            Debug.Log("Test1");
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Medium")) GUILayout.Width(100);
        {
            powerSetting.floatValue = 0.0001f;
            powerSettingText = "0.0001f";
            Debug.Log("Test2");
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Slow")) GUILayout.Width(100);
        {
           powerSetting.floatValue = 0.00001f;
        }
       
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal(); 
        GUILayout.TextField(powerSettingText);



        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    
}`
```

I have tried everything I can think of. Makes no sense. I also tried custom editor window. There it just does same thing when I hover anywhere over the window. I'm sure it's something simple but Ahhh!!!! Driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these

```
// without the wrapping "{ }" the if condition only is applied to the first expression after it
//                            | which is this!
//                            v 
if (GUILayout.Button("Fast")) GUILayout.Width(100);
// the scope below is always executed
{
    powerSetting.floatValue = 0.001f;
    powerSettingText = "0.001f";
    Debug.Log("Test1");
}
```

are basically equivalent to

```
 if (GUILayout.Button("Fast"))
 {
     GUILayout.Width(100);  
 }
 // code block below is in its own scope but still always executed
 {
     powerSetting.floatValue = 0.001f;
     powerSettingText = "0.001f";
     Debug.Log("Test1");
 }
```

I think you see the issue by now ;)

It should rather be e.g.

```
                             // this is supposed to be an argument to the Button call
if (GUILayout.Button("Fast", GUILayout.Width(100)))
{
    powerSetting.floatValue = 0.001f;
    powerSettingText = "0.001f";
    Debug.Log("Test1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It has been a while for me. Picking something back up after a couple years. I will give this a try. :)

Comment: Ok, so figured it out ... This was the issue.................. if (GUILayout.Button("Fast")) GUILayout.Width(100); ............. It meeds to be ..........if (GUILayout.Button("Fast", GUILayout.Width(100))) ... not sure why that would cause that issue but either way, problem solved. There was nothing wrong with my if statement. That was correct.

Comment: @Darren well .. no, your `if` statement **was** wrong ^^ As explained in the answer is causes your blocks to be executed always so pretty much not behaving as you desired/thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check you are closing all the if before. So you are only running inside the true the GuiLayout.Width, the block bellow is always run a cause that is not part of the if.

Example:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Medium", GUILayout.Width(100)))
{
    powerSetting.floatValue = 0.0001f;
    powerSettingText = "0.0001f";
    Debug.Log("Test2");
}
```